# NOT IN nested sub query returns empty set and thus no results for join

Tags: mysql, select

I'm writing a spring batch program that is looking for item that is about to expire. Works fine but I notice something going wrong in one of my tests. This is a new batch program that relies on another new table to keep track of expired items that it has reported on. For example:

- Get Item about to expire that don't have an entry in vendor_notification table
- Send Email
- Other business logic
- Create entry in vendor_notificaton table

Here's my sql statement

```
select * from item join vendor_notification 
where item.item_id NOT IN(SELECT vendor_notification.item_id 
FROM vendor_notification);
```

Which works fine as long as there is data in the vendor_notification table. However, once I reset and clear out the test data no results are returned. If I add a row to the vendor_notification table and a new row to item then I do get that new row.

Is there a better way of doing the above query so that I handle an empty returned set for the nested query?

Comment: `NOT IN`  empty set should return everything. The `join vendor_notification` with no join condition should be removed. Surprised that is valid syntax.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not an expert in mySql but I'm doing the above statement directly against the DB. If that table is empty I would think it would return an empty set for the nested select but it appears to be returning null (since the NOT IN returns nothing as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the inner query returns null, the NOT IN clause will evaluate to false.

```
select * from item 
where (SELECT count(vendor_notification.item_id) 
FROM vendor_notification WHERE vendor_notification.item_id = item.item_id) = 0;
```

The inner query now returns the count of matching records, which will zero if there are none.

Comment: That worked nicely, thank you. I knew there was a better way of doing that just didn't see it.

Comment: Please correct the first sentence. There is a difference between an empty set and a set containing `NULL`. If there are zero results, the NOT IN clause will evaluate to **true**. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46278/2)

Comment: I think the actual issue for the OP was that the `JOIN` without a join condition does a cross join and *cross joining* onto an empty table will reduce the rows to `0` BTW. As in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46278/6)